# How to create movable activity?

Tags: android, material-design, android-5.0-lollipop

please i want to know how i can perform a movable activity that appears from bottom and stuck in the middle of screen, like android lollipop contact details or android lollipop chooser. 
I want to stop activity if user move it to bottom, like this picture of Borel's detail

[Borel detail picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCbMf.png)

Comment: Did you at least try to solve that on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BottomSheetDialog in design support library.
An example below.

```
        BottomSheetDialog mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
        mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view);
        mBottomSheetDialog.show();
```